# How to send message over CAN using Python?

Tags: python, can-bus

I am new to Python and want to send a CAN bus message through python. I have NI usb can adapter I am hoping will work. How can I get on the right track?

Comment: https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/# Have a look at this library. It may be useful.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the link. Great start. Hope it will get me where I need to be.

Comment: Scapy (use development version from github) also provides a way to parse CAN packets, and sockets that use `python-can`, it might help: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#automotive-usage

Answer (score 1):

CAN msgs are usually sent from the system path, for you to generate CAN msg in python script

Use the following format

```
import os

os.system(cansend 123#112233)
```

You can define your logics in with this basic syntax